# Find the unit vectors that are parallel to the tangent line to the parabola $y=x^2$ at the point $(2,4)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Can someone explain to me why the parallel vector is $i+4j$? The picture is the answer key. When I did the question I used the point given in the question, which is $2i+4j$.

Comment: Same question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20762/finding-the-unit-vectors-parallel-to-a-tangent-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 2i + 4j does not have a slope of 4, it has a slope of 2 (Rise over Run)
The line through (2,4) and the Origin is not a tangent to the parabola, but a secant

Comment: Thanks, all the reminder I need to understand this question. Will accept answer in 7 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Let the unit vector be:
$$cos(x)i+ sin(x)j$$
You have $$tan(x)=4$$
Now substitute $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$ in the first equation.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent has gradient $4$ which is the derivative.

The points on the tangent line can therefore be written as $(2+t,4+4t)$ - different values of $t$ give different points

or $(2,4)+(1,4)t$

or $(2+t)i+(4+4t)j$

or $2i+4j+(i+4j)t$

It is the variable part which gives you a vector parallel to the tangent.

Answer (score 0):

You know slope of the tangent line is $4$ so the parallel vector should have $y$ component $4$ times the $x$ component so the most obvious parallel vector is $1i+4j$.